# Row is not being deleted because of cascade trigger updates this row

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, cascade, sql-delete

I have problem with deleteing rows in table which has trigger which invokes trigger of second table, which updates row in first table. Here is the description:

```
Table A (id,b_table_count) 
Table B (id,a_table_id_fk)
```

Table A has trigger BEFORE DELETE which has instructions:

```
BEGIN  
DELETE FROM b where a_table_fk = OLD.id;  
RETURN OLD;  
END;
```

Table B has trigger AFTER DELETE with instruction:

```
UPDATE a SET b_table_count = b_table_count-1 WHERE OLD.a_table_id_fk = a.id;
```

When I delete row from table A, which has no connected rows in B, everything is correct.
But, when I delete row from table A, which has connected row(s) in table B, then DELETE statement returns  "Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected" . I must execute DELETE statment second time, then row is finnaly deleted. After first DELTE only connected ROWS are deleted in TABLE B, but row being deleted in table A remains.

Do you have answer for that? I suspect that pgsql doesn't allow to update row being deleted in trigger, but I haven't found anything about it in pgsql documentation. 
What is the solution?

Comment: why not use `ON DELETE CASCADE` instead of the first trigger?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a similar problem, but with one table only. Deleting rows from the given table fires a trigger (before delete), that searches for related rows int the same table (by a given condition), and if finds them, these rows get updated. Now, if an updated row is to be deleted by the same delete command, then it doesn't gets deleted.

*So basically, if you create a trigger, that always updates the same row that is being deleted, you can't delete anything from now on.*

I don't know if this is on purpose, or not. From one way, it seems logical, that's for sure. If you update a record, it's not the same record that was intended for deletion.

(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

So basicly you have a A -> trigger -> B -> trigger -> A situation, which is actually incorrect thing to do by design and I think postgres locks the row that is executing trigger or A row is locked but i'm not sure about all inner behavior of postgres.

so you can try DELETE FROM B WHERE a_id = %Row_to_delete_id% first and then 
DELETE FROM A WHERE a_id = %Row_to_delete_id%, in a transaction,

but i highly recommend you revise your trigger dependencies

Comment: At first i had no trigger dependecies(no trigger in table A), because i had foreign key in table B (a_table_id_fk) ON DELETE CASCADE. It was incorrect and there was a lock when i was deleteing row from table A. I changed to solution which i described in my post, but it is still incorrect. So do i  must to resign from trigger in table A? Maybe prepare something substitute like special pl/pgsql function to delete rows in table A which will be also deleteing rows in table B?